# Writing code to count features in Google Earth Pro

Tags: google-earth

Imagine we have multiple distinct features on Google Earth Pro that are visible across a large area for a certain image date. Is it possible to write code (in which program I do not know) that will identify these shapes, measure their area, and export that file into an .xls with lat-long coordinates for each identified feature?

Comment: What kind of features is it?

Comment: They look like swimming pools, but are in different sizes and sometimes different shapes (e.g., square, rectangle). But these pools have distinct features, like a plastic lining around them that is easily visible from the imagery.

Comment: How are the features stored?  Are they stored in a KML file that you have open in Google Earth, or are the features streamed from a external server?  What kind of geometry is each pool stored as?  Also, what other tools do you have access to?

Comment: Yes. In a KML file in Earth. We can think about it as pools in peoples' backyards that are visible on Google Earth. I'm not sure how to answer your other questions, in terms of the tools I have access to. I can easily get the coordinates and measure the surface area of each pool manually, but if there are thousands, it becomes challenging.

Comment: If you have access to, for example, QGIS, it reads and can open KML files.  Using its Python API, it would be relatively straightforward to go through all the pools in your KML file, compute the area for each, and output it to a CSV File that could be opened in Excel.  That assumes that each pool is presented in the KML as a polygon.  If' it's individual point markers, short of doing some machine learning, unfortunately, you'd probably have to measure them manually.

Comment: Right. I do have QGIS and could you Python API. I should have been clearer: If I wanted to count the pools across, for example, Dallas TX, and none were marked using the point markers within the KML, I wanted to know whether I could define one pool, and have a program to find other similar pools, count and measure, and export them. But maybe you're saying ML is needed for this instead? Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to do that, yes. If the pools are polygons you could use python to get the area of each pool, along with the count and it's coordinates.  No need for ML in that case.  If the pools were just points that you had dropped on pools, then there's no way to measure the pool's area.  But you mentioned that they are not points, so that's good. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Thanks, Turbo. One more quick question. I haven't marked them as polygons on Earth (i.e., I haven't drawn a polygon around each). But they are fairly distinctive pools. That is, I'm thinking if I open Google Earth, go to a specific area on the globe, and find these pools without drawing polygons or adding points, is it possible to code it in Python to ID them, measure, and then export coordinates. I'm not sure how I would code in these characteristics for each pool, however. But that is a different question.